# What is the correct syntax for rsyslog's re_match()?

Tags: regular-expression, rsyslog, filter

I'm trying to filter unwanted messages from a cron job (systemd) from rsyslog output. However rsyslog always complains about the second argument of `re_match()`. The filter rule I have is:

```
if $programname == "systemd" and re_match($msg, '^Started [Ss]ession \d+ of user ntpmon\.$') then stop
```

I started putting the regex in double-quotes, and rsyslog complained. Then I put the regex in single quotes, and rsyslog still complains.

The documentation is a bit vague:

```
re_match(expr, re)

    returns 1, if expr matches re, 0 otherwise. Uses POSIX ERE.
```

How do I fix it (the filter, not the docs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double the backslash, otherwise rsyslog tries to interpret `\d` as an escape sequence within a string, and this is not parseable. So it should be `\\d`.

But `\d` is not a Posix ERE. You presumably meant `[0-9]`, for example, for a digit. So try

```
'^Started [Ss]ession [0-9]+ of user ntpmon\\.$'
```

Comment: Exactly! The main problem were the error messages of rsyslog: They were not helpful at all, and the other problem is the poor documentation. Well, and I had thought it might use Perl-compatible regular expressions. ;-)

Comment: Maybe an additional question: How could I use sub-matches, like `user (.+)` to check several users without repeating the whole expression?

Comment: You can certainly use parentheses like `(.+)`  to group part of a pattern.

Comment: I know, the question is how to reference the matched value: Like `re_match(...) and $1 == "blabla"`? (In Perl it would be `$1`, in sed it would be `\1`,... SO what would it be in rsyslog?

Comment: You can use `re_extract()` to set a variable, which I think you can use in an `if` expression. But if it is only to later test if the var is "abc" or "def", then simply use `(abc|def)` in the original re_match.